# import com.google.code... cant be resolved

Tags: android, google-api

I was trying to use the apndroids source code for a project but the following code says it cannot be resolved.

```
import com.google.code.apndroid.Constants;
import com.google.code.apndroid.IActionService;
```

I installed a google api addon and used that as my build but it doesnt have the com.google.code.
Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Did you check that you added any necessary .jar files to your build?